# A board game with astronauts?

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was younger my parents bought a few board games and left them at my grandparents for us.

There was one game which had a plastic space ship mounted on a stick over the board, and it had a pump to propel the astronauts **into the spaceship**. You moved around the board and then when you got to the end you could pump your astronaut(s) into the spaceship.

I think there was a spinner similar to the one in the Game of Life, and the astronauts were green, blue, red and yellow.

Does anyone have any idea what game this might be?

Comment: Roughly what year would this have been?

Comment: This was during the mid-late 90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying to figure this out for the longest time and I finally just did! I loved this game as a kid and couldn't remember what it was!! It's KooKooNauts!

Comment: This was it. It's barely available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[Rocket Race](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22914/rocket-race) appears to involve a pump:

> An innovative space game with a real flying rocket! The astronauts are trying to get home from the alien planet but the air from the ground keeps blowing them off the path – the players use the pump to control the air streams. The first one to reach the rocket safely gets to fly home in it!

You could look at [the image gallery](http://boardgamegeek.com/images/boardgame/22914/rocket-race) to see for sure whether it's what you remember. It's hard to see from those pictures but it does have a spinner too, according to [the rules](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/UK/01535.pdf). The astronaut pieces are the colors you mentioned, too, though those are pretty common color choices.

Comment: I don't think this is it. The pump sends the astronauts use into the spaceship and the board was flatter.

Comment: This game propels the spaceship, but not the astronauts into it. Definitely not it.

Comment: The date is much more convincing; this came out in 2006. (No offense, but everyone's memories can be a bit inaccurate after 20 years.) Not sure if there's an older version, so I figured I'd leave the answer in case it helps someone find the right answer (and to keep other people from suggesting the same).